# The outline of my bar is wider than the bar in my bar chart for ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I've written the code below where I want a thick outline for the minimum value within my figures but a dashed outline for the maximum value of my figures. However, the maximum value outline is always larger than the actual largest bar. How do I figure this?

This is my code. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong because it is pretty much the same.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create a function to add outlines to the bars with the highest and lowest values
add_outlines <- function(data) {
    max_values <- data %>%
    group_by(performance_metric, evaluation) %>%
    filter(value == max(value))
  
    min_values <- data %>%
    group_by(performance_metric, evaluation) %>%
    filter(value == min(value))
  
  p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = model, y = value, fill = model)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    facet_grid(performance_metric ~ evaluation, scales = "free_y") +
    labs(y = "Value") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = "right") +
    scale_fill_discrete(name = "Model") +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0, 0.3))) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = NULL)
  
  p <- p + geom_bar(
    data = min_values,
    aes(x = model, y = value, fill = model),
    stat = "identity",
    position = position_identity(), # Use position_identity to maintain original width
    color = "black",  # Set outline color to black
    size = 1  # Set outline size
  )
  
  # Create a separate layer for the highest values with dashed outline
  p <- p + geom_bar(
    data = max_values,
    aes(x = model, y = value, fill = model),
    stat = "identity",
    position = position_identity(), # Use position_identity to maintain original width
    color = "black",  # Set outline color to black
    size = 1,  # Set outline size
    linetype = "dashed",  # Set the outline to dashed line for highest values
    fill = NA, 
    scale_size(guide = "none")# Remove fill color for outlines
  )
  
  return(p)
}

# Create the plot with bars having black dashed outlines for the highest values
# and solid outlines for the lowest values
plot_with_outlines <- add_outlines(df)

# Print or display the plot
print(plot_with_outlines)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! At first glance I would guess that you could achieve your result more easily. However, without [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data it's nearly impossible to figure out what's the issue, how your issue could be fixed or how your code could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing occurs because when you add the additional `geom_bar` layers for the maximum and minimum bars, the bars are effectively drawn on top of the original bars. This makes the outline seem "larger" than the actual bar for the maximum values.

The key to fixing this is to not re-draw the bar for the max and min values, but just to add the outlines. You can achieve this by setting `fill = NA` so that the bars are transparent, leaving only the outlines.

Here's how you can adjust your code to achieve the desired effect:

1. First, make sure you don't redefine the bars when adding outlines
   for min and max. Only set the outline-specific aesthetics.
2. Ensure you don't redraw the bars by setting `fill = NA` for both min
   and max outlines.

Your code is mostly right, but you seem to have added a redundant `fill` aesthetic for the `max_values`. Let's adjust it:

```
# ... [rest of your code remains unchanged] ...

p <- p + geom_bar(
    data = min_values,
    aes(x = model, y = value),
    stat = "identity",
    position = position_identity(),
    color = "black",
    fill = NA,  # Set fill to NA
    size = 1
)

p <- p + geom_bar(
    data = max_values,
    aes(x = model, y = value),
    stat = "identity",
    position = position_identity(),
    color = "black",
    fill = NA,  # Set fill to NA
    size = 1,
    linetype = "dashed"
)

# ... [rest of your code remains unchanged] ...
```

By ensuring that the bars for the min and max values are transparent `fill = NA`, only the outlines will be visible, and they will directly overlay the original bars, giving the appearance of just a thicker outline.

Comment: Hi Mashrur, Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I did try this and it still produces the same result where only the dashed outline is larger than the bar. Not sure why this isn't doing it for the minimum values, only the maximum values.